# Update or Insert records in database based on result set

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a table like this

[image]

I've another table `sections` in which there are 6 sections with id from `1 to 6`. I get a list of section id from user which gives information about the current active section of user. Suppose the list returned to me has section ids as follows `{2,3,4,5}` for user with id `1`. Now my question is

1. How can I pass this list of section ids to my stored procedure
2. I want to update is active flag of record where section id is 1 and user id is 1  since the list of section ids doesn't have an entry of 1
3. I want to insert a new record of section id 5 for user id 1 in same table as it is returned in list of section ids.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

I can get `total section id's` from the following query

```
select Id from sections
```

but don't know i will iterate between `total list of section id's` and compare the `list of section ids` returned from C#

Comment: Take a look at: [Table valued parameters](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: @EdwinStoteler : Thanks for help.. but first step is to pass the list of id's and then there is another part to change `IsActive` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created a method which would call stored procedure, to that method I passed a list of `sections`(sections table entity) and Customer Id

```
public bool SaveChatSectionUserMapping(List<Sections> lstSections, int customerId)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            bool isUpdated = false;
            try
            {
                string xmlString = string.Empty;
                xmlString = XMLOperations.WriteXML(lstSections);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateSections", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@XMLData", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerId;
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
                param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                param.ParameterName = "@Result";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                isUpdated = (param.Value != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToBoolean(param.Value) : false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }
            return isUpdated;
        }
```

The value of xmlString I get from this line `xmlString = XMLOperations.WriteXML(lstSections);` is like this

```
<ArrayOfSection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Sections>
    <UserId>1</UserId>
    <SectionId>1</SectionId>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  </Sections>
  <Sections>
    <UserId>1</UserId>
    <SectionId>2</SectionId>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  </Sections>
  <Sections>
    <UserId>1</UserId>
    <SectionId>5</SectionId>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  </Sections>
</ArrayOfSection>
```

Now in stored Procedure

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[spUpdateSections]  
(  
 @XMLData as XML,
 @CustomerId INT,  
 @Result int Output

)  
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    Declare @ErrorCode Varchar(100) = '',@propertyCount VArchar(100) = '',@currentCount int=1,@SectionId int, @IsActive bit

Begin TRY

UPDATE Sections
SET
    IsActive = 0
WHERE
    UserId = @CustomerId

SELECT @propertyCount = convert(VARCHAR, @XMLData.query ('count(/ArrayOfSection/Sections)'))
SET @currentCount = 1

     while (@currentCount<=@propertyCount)       
     Begin 
     SET @SectionId = @XMLData.value('data(/ArrayOfSection/Sections[sql:variable("@currentCount")]/SectionId)[1]', 'INT') 
     SET @IsActive = @XMLData.value('data(/ArrayOfSection/Sections[sql:variable("@currentCount")]/IsActive)[1]', 'BIT')

               If Exists (SELECT *
                          FROM
                              Sections
                          WHERE
                              UserId = @CustomerId
                              AND SectionId = @SectionId)
BEGIN
       IF(@IsActive=1) 
       BEGIN 
            UPDATE Sections
             SET
                 IsActive = 1
             WHERE
                 UserId = @CustomerId AND
                 SectionId = @SectionId

        END
END

ELSE
       BEGIN
       IF(@IsActive=1) 
       BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Sections
           ([SectionId]
           ,[UserId]
           ,[IsActive])
     VALUES
           (@SectionId,@CustomerId,1)
        END
    END

SET @currentCount = @currentCount + 1 
       End 

       SET @Result = 1
           ErrorCode:  
           If(@ErrorCode !='')
           BEGIN
--SELECT @BSErrorResult = doctor.GetErrorCodeDetail(@ErrorCode)
SET @Result = 2
           END  
    END TRY        
    BEGIN CATCH     
      --Declaring Variable for formating error  
      Declare @ErrorMessage  VARCHAR(max),  
       @ErrorSeverity  INT,  
       @ErrorState   INT

--SELECTING TECHNICAL ERROR   
SELECT @ErrorMessage = error_message()
     , @ErrorSeverity = error_severity()
     , @ErrorState = error_state()
     , @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage + '  ' + db_name() + '  ' + ' ' + object_name(@@PROCID);   

      RAISERROR (  
         @ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
         @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
         @ErrorState -- State.  
           );   
     End CATCH    



END
```

Another way to Generate XMl would be by using `XElement` like this

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Sections",
                                from col in lstSections
                                select new XElement("rows",
                                               new XElement("UserId", col.UserId),
                                               new XElement("SectionId", col.SectionId),
                                               new XElement("IsActive", col.IsActive)));

                              string  xmlString = xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the complete question.

**1. Like I said in the comment: [Table valued parameters](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)**

First create a [UDTT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) to store your sections ids for input for the stored procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SectionIdUDTT] AS TABLE(
    [id] int NOT NULL
)
```

Use this UDTT as a parameter for your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourSPname] @SectionId SectionIdUDTT readonly,
    @UserId INT
AS
BEGIN
```

In order to call this stored procedure you must first fill the SectionIdUDTT before you call the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @SectionId AS SectionIdUDTT;

INSERT INTO @SectionId 
--your values here

EXEC YourSPname @SectionId, @UserId;
```

Take a look at [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) class in order to call this from C#. Make sure the user has execute permissions on the UDTT.

**2 in the stored procedure**

Set the records to inactive of the user that already existed but are not in the table valued parameter.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET IsActive = 0
WHERE UserId = @UserId
    AND SectionId NOT IN (SELECT id FROM @SectionId)
    AND SectionId IN (SELECT Id FROM sections) --Not really needed
```

**3 in the stored procedure**

Just insert the record that not yet exists. I just assume that `id` is an identity column.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (UserId, SectionId, IsActive)
SELECT @UserId,
    s.id,
    1
FROM @SectionId s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable y
    WHERE y.SectionId = s.id
        AND y.UserId = @UserId
    )
```

I would recommend [Transaction management](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) in your stored procedure.